# Error Exporting a component without importing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

The following is my files:

Pricing.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Table } from 'react-bootstrap';

class Pricing extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Table striped bordered condensed>
                <thead>
                <th></th>
                <th>Community</th>
                <th>Business</th>
                <th>Enterprise</th>
                </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Cost</td>
                <td>Free</td>
                <td>Free</td>
                <td>Free</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            </Table>
        );
    }
}

export default Pricing;
```

index.js

```
export { Pricing }  from './Pricing';
```

Main.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Pricing from '../../pages/Pricing';

const Main = () => (
    <main>
        <Switch>
            <Route path='/pricing' component={Pricing}/>
        </Switch>
    </main>
)

export default Main;
```

I get the following error:

35:70-77 "export 'default' (imported as 'Pricing') was not found in '../../pages/Pricing'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take any of the below options

First import and then export the pricing component from your `index.js` file

```
import Pricing from './Pricing'
export { Pricing }
```

**or else you need to export the `default` component like**

```
export { default as Pricing }  from './Pricing';
```

**or change the export to be a named export in `Pricing.js`**

```
export { Pricing };
export default Pricing;
```

and use it like

```
export { Pricing }  from './Pricing';
```

I you wish to **export the Pricing component as a default export** from your index.js you could just write

```
export {default} from './Pricing';
```

Comment: can't he just do `export default Pricing   from './Pricing';`

Comment: A default export is essentially exported by the name `default` and you need to actually write `export {default as Pricing} from './Pricing';` as far as I know

Comment: The last option was what I was looking for.  Changed all my index.js files to `export { default } from './File'`