# export default usage with deconstruct

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I came to a codebase that did this

```
//index.js
export { default } from './Tabs'
export { default as Tab } from './Tab'

//Tab.js
export default class Tab extends Component {
  render() => 'Something'
}
```

It's understandable that the author put Tab files under a Tab folder so that in other place he can just do import './Tabs' but why within the index.js he need to deconstruct?

Comment: Are you asking about `Tabs.js` or `Tab.js` ? Can you also post index.js code snippet ?

Comment: @Mad-D Both. The index.js code has just 2 lines.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of people follow this nomenclature where the index file is just exports which then makes the imports easier.

It lets you import from the Tabs folder without explicitly saying the index.js filename. Most importantly it lets you import things from the folder Tab in just one statement.

For Example:

// Tab/Tab.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Tab extends Component {
  render() {
    return <span>Tab</span>;
  }
}
export default Tab;
```

// Tab/Tabs.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Tabs extends Component {
  render() {
    return <span>Tabs</span>;
  }
}
export default Tabs;
```

// Tab/index.js

```
export Tab from "./Tab";
export Tabs from "./Tabs";
```

// Main file

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Tab, Tabs } from "./Tab";


const App = () => (
  <div>
    <Tab />
    <Tabs />
  </div>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/rr6klxj5j4

Comment: does this not answer your question @Melissa92

Answer (score 0):

You can have a single default export from your file, Also writing

```
//index.js
export Tabs from './Tabs'
export Tab from './Tab'
```

will export them as a named export  which you can later import as

```
import { Tabs, Tab } from './Tabs'
```

Also to understand the point default import is nothing different from an export named as default, so when you write

```
//index.js
export { default } from './Tabs'     // Exports the Tabs as default
export { default as Tab } from './Tab' // imports the default from Tab and exports it as Tab
```

You could also write the above as

```
export { default } from './Tabs'
export Tab from './Tab'
```

In the above two cases you would import them as

```
import Tabs, { Tab } from './Tabs'
```

Check [Error Exporting a component without importing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48359823/error-exporting-a-component-without-importing/48359865#48359865) for some more details

Comment: What is the different btw `export { default } from './Tabs'
` and `export default from './Tabs'`?

Comment: You can write it as export default from './Tabs' too. Its just two different ways of writing the same